# Why am I getting "Grammatical Error" in LTspice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice, transfer-function

Why am I getting "Grammatical Error" in LTspice the instant that my transfer function denominator goes from a 2nd order to a 3rd order system? See below.

[image]

Please note that the transfer function depicted is not the actual TF that I'm checking for. It's the 1st one that I have arrived at as part of a "check and test" process to see why the actual TF receives the same message.

If the \$s^3\$ term is removed from the TF, the circuit would simulate without no problem. But, the moment that I include an \$s^3\$ term into it, I get the "Grammatical Error" message.

Any insight that anybody can provide will be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Your `s^3` is badly spelled: `s***3`. That's three `*`, not two. LTspice accepts both `**` and `^` for exponentiation in `Laplace` transfer functions (but only there).

Comment: Hahaha. I don't know what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `s^2` and `s^3` to see if it makes a difference. I didn't parse the formula visually other than to ascertain that `S**2` or `s**3` might need to be placed inside their own parentheses to avoid formula confusion so, you could also confirm this by using (`s**2`) and (`s**3`).